# Finding the value of bounded linear functional

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In the $\ell^2$ space with:$$\|f\| = \sup\{|f(x)| : x\in \ell, \|x\| \le 1\}$$
Where $f(x)=\sum \frac{x_n} {3^n}$.

I need to find the value of $||f||$. I am a beginner and I haven't ever dealt with such problems. Please suggest how can I calculate its value?

Comment: It is relevant whether or not the sum if from $0\to\infty$ or $1\to\infty$

Comment: Look up for the Riesz representation theorem in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @FShrike The summation is from 1 to $\infty$

Comment: @BazyliZuczek I haven't read about its application, please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riesz Representation Theorem establishes that fact that any bounded linear functional over a Hilbert space $H$ is of the form
$$
f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle
$$
for some $y\in H$. And in that case, $\|f\|=\|y\|$. This solves is automatically in your case.

A less sophisticated way of doing exactly the same is to apply Cauchy Schwarz and work toward finding which $x$ approximates equality. In your case that would be
$$
|f(x)|\leq \|x\|\,\Big(\sum_n\frac1{3^{2n}}\Big)^{1/2}
$$
In this case it is kind of obvious that the inequality will be an equality if
$$
x=\sum_n\frac1{3^n}\,e_n.
$$

Comment: I have understood the rest of it except how did we know that $
|f(x)|\leq \|x\|\,\Big(\sum_n\frac1{3^{2n}}\Big)^{1/2}
$?

Comment: It's the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. You cannot do anything on Hilbert spaces without it.

Comment: My bad. Got it. Thanks.